# Load Javascript array with MYSQL database data

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

suppose i have an javascript array "userName".I want to load it from a database table named "user".

Can anyone help with idea or sample code?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean the content of your array is stored in database, or you want to get the code to create the array from the database ?

Comment: Usually Javascript cannot talk directly to a database, you'll need something in between. How are you talking to the database?

Comment: @Guillaume:I want to get code to create array from database
@deceze:i use php..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use ajax and php as an intermediate :

1. Define an empty JS array :

   `var myarray = new Array();`
2. use ajax to call your php script, javascript will eval the output by PHP (note this uses prototype library):

   ```
    new Ajax.Request('myfile.php', {

       onSuccess : function(xmlHTTP) {

           eval(mlHTTP.responseText);
       }

   });
   ```
3. Write your PHP code to grab data and print JS code (it must be valid javscript !) :

   ```
   $i=0; $q=mysql_query('select ..');

   while($row=mysql_fetch_array($q)){               

       echo "myarray[".$i."]='".$row['data']."';";

       $i++;  
   }
   ```
4. You can check that your Js array contains data :

   ```
   alert(myarray.length);
   ```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

You'll have to use the `mysql_connect()`, `mysql_select_db()` functions in PHP to connect to your db. After that use `mysql_query()` to SELECT the fields in your user table (if your user table has the fields name and id, `SELECT name, id FROM user`). Then you can fetch all infos from the db with `mysql_fetch_assoc()` or any other mysql fetch function. Now you need to `echo` your data into the javascript on your website, formatted as an array. This is complicated to get right, but you can get help from `json_encode`.

To fill your array with the user names, you'd do something like this.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var userName = <?php
            // Connect to MySQL
            //mysql_connect();
            //mysql_select_db();
            $d = mysql_query( "SELECT name, id FROM user" ) or die( mysql_error() );
            $usernames = array();
            while( $r = mysql_fetch_assoc($d) ) {
                $usernames[] = $r['name'];
            }
            echo json_encode( $usernames );
        ?>;
        // Do something with the userName array here
    </script>
    </head>
```

Answer (score 4):

This creates a global `user` variable in your page.

```
<?php
    $user = /* get information from database the way you usually do */;
    // $user == array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'foo', ...);
?>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var user = <?php echo json_encode($user); ?>;
</script>
```

If you're looking for a dynamic AJAXy solution, follow some tutorials about AJAX.

Comment: i actually don't want mix of javascript php code to do this...i have separate javascript and php script  and from javascript  i want to call php script to get database data....

Comment: @Rony In that case you'll have to brush up on AJAX, which you can use to load some information from the server. If the `user` variable doesn't change though, this method is better and saves an extra roundtrip to the server.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do that simply is to get your data in your php code, and then "write" the javascript code to generate the array in php.

A short example would be :

```
echo "a = new Array();";
foreach($row in $results)
{
  echo "a[$row[0]] = $row[1];";
}
```

My code could be quite incorrect, it's juste to give you a quick example.

You could also do that in a more elegant way, using json.

Comment: i actually don't want mix of javascript php code to do this...i have separate javascript and php script  and from javascript  i want to call php script to get database data....

Comment: You can then make an ajax request to a piece of php code, which would give you the data in json, xml, or anything you like.